# Firestore real-time remove or modify

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

I am using Firestore for a test project, just to see what capabilities it has. Everything functions as it should, except I am having some trouble running the real-time capabilities of the database. First I initialize the database and pass in the credentials.

A new list is created and added to the document in a div element. Then I call the onSnapshot() method on my collection that I want to be monitored in real-time. Everything works fine when an element gets added, I have a hard time finding how to do the same for the "removed" and "modified" paths..

What can I do to monitor in real-time items being removed or modified?

```
// variables based on the newly created firebase db
const db = firebase.firestore();
const colRef = db.collection("werknemers");

// RETRIEVE RECORDS IN REAL TIME 
// I create a list and append it to the element 
var list = document.createElement('ol');
document.getElementById("check").appendChild(list);

// at changes in reference collection onSnapshot() is called 
colRef.onSnapshot(snapshot => {

    // Listen for document metadata changes
    includeMetadataChanges: true;

    // for each change in the document 
    snapshot.docChanges().forEach(function(change) {

      // adding functions 
      if (change.type == "added"){

        let list_item = document.createElement("li");
        list_item.className = "list_item_class";
        list.appendChild(list_item);
        list_item.innerHTML = change.doc.data().departement + " " +   change.doc.data().naam;

      }

      // removed is called, remove something from your list 
      else if (change.type == "removed"){

      }

      // modified is called 
      else if (change.type == "modified"){

      }
    }, function(error){

        console.log("an error has occurred during realtime change process");

  });
});
```

Comment: The database you're using is Cloud Firestore, which is a completely separate database from the Realtime Database. While both databases are part of Firebase, they are separate and each have their own API. Please use correct product names and tags, to increase the chances of getting help.

Comment: Thank you Frank, my mistake.. I appreciate the advice and the edit!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are three main cases you'll need to handle:

1. When a document is added to the database, you'll want to add an element for that document to the HTML.
2. When a document is removed from the database, you'll want to remove that document's element from the HTML.
3. When a document is updated in the database, you'll want to update that document's element in the HTML.

Since removing and updating require that you can find the element for a document in the HTML, you'll want to make sure that you include the document ID in the HTML element (typically as its ID).

```
snapshot.docChanges().forEach(function(change) {
  if (change.type == "added"){
    let list_item = document.createElement("li");
    list_item.className = "list_item_class";
    list_item.id = change.doc.id;
    list.appendChild(list_item);
    list_item.innerHTML = change.doc.data().departement + " " +   change.doc.data().naam;
  }
  else if (change.type == "removed"){
    let list_item = document.getElementById(change.doc.id);
    if (list_item) {
      list_item.parentNode.removeChild(listItem);
    }
  }
  else if (change.type == "modified"){
    let list_item = document.getElementById(change.doc.id);
    if (list_item) {
      list_item.innerHTML = change.doc.data().departement + " " +   change.doc.data().naam;
    }
  }
}, function(error){
    console.log("an error has occurred during realtime change process");
});
```